# What protects starships from debris floating in space?

Tags: star-trek

What protects starships from being damaged by debris floating in space, such as comets and asteroids? Especially during warp travel it seems likely the chances the ship would run into something are high.

I don't think they always raise shields before engaging the warp drives, shields seem to be used sparingly and if they were left on by default there wouldn't be all those instances where the Captain ordered them to be raised.

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deflector_shield

Comment: @Richard a starship doesn't always have it's (primary) deflector shields up, otherwise the captain would never have to order them up.

Comment: Are you asking about when the ship is in motion or when the ship is at rest/orbit?

Comment: You're confusing the main shield with the deflector shield...

Comment: Also see http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Navigational_deflector ...as Richard says, this is distinct from defensive shields.

Comment: "Stars occupy minute areas of space.  They are clustered a few billion here and a few billion there, as if seeking consolation in numbers.  Space does not care."  In other words: space is BIG and the debris you mention are SMALL.  You've probably more chance of an airliner being hit by a bird during takeoff.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - At warp speed, the odds of hitting *something* big enough to destroy your ship are very very high. At warp 1 and above, a hydrogen molecule would plough through 10 metres of plating and/or create sufficient radiation to kill a man; http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn18532-starship-pilots-speed-kills-especially-warp-speed.html#.U636FvldWSo

Comment: @Richard Due to the physics of warp fields, the ship isn't actually travelling that fast, and [a collision isn't going to cause _that much_ damage](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22570/2242)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the [Deflector Shields](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deflector_shield) (which are powerful and energy-hungry) with the [Navigational Deflectors](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Navigational_deflector) (which are relatively weak and low-powered).

The Navigational Deflector is a series of nested shields that extend a huge distance from the ship and are used to divert small incoming particles from hitting the hull of the ship when the vessel enters warp.

This is opposed to the Ship's main Deflector Shield which is manually operated ("***raise shields!***") and is used to prevent larger items as well as energy beams and explosions from impacting the hull.

The (fully-canon)  [TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) offers a diagram of how the system operates:

[image]

And the (semi-canon) [Voyager Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_Technical_Manual) clarifies the key differences between the two systems:

[image]

Comment: Sort of the reverse of a [Bussard ramjet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet).

Comment: @Xantec - Yes and no. The deflectors can also be configured to collect interstellar hydrogen as well as push it away; http://i.stack.imgur.com/WPRdv.png

Comment: Note that a scene in the second "Year of Hell" episode from Voyager shows that sans the shields, the ship can be very vulnerable to debris like micro-asteroids.

Comment: @joshbirk - Yes, I was trying to work out whether it was worth adding to my answer. In the end, the lack of a good visual put me off; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYj5l0mGL-Y

Comment: They only ever call it the deflector, deflectors or deflector field. Chances are it was the navigational deflector, rather than the shields.

Comment: @Richard - I can see that, without the backstory that the ship is so damaged that it can't keep the Nav deflector up the scenes don't show much.  Still, one of the better moments in VOY

Comment: In real-world warp theory, all objects are bent out of the way along with spacetime as an object moves through space.