# Warp - Warp collisions / battle in Star Trek

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I have been looking at some of the questions on the site about Warp collisions with stationary or non-warp speed particles, but is there any example (canon or otherwise) that discusses a battle taking place at warp in Star Trek? I'm not aware of any but wonder if anyone has looked at this before. [Has there ever been a warp / non-warp collision?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/219929/has-there-ever-been-a-warp-non-warp-collision)

I know the worm-hole from deep space nine allowed for multiple craft during the Dominion wars but am wondering if warp bubbles are exclusive or could be entered. Most notable example in [Sacrifice of Angels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_(episode))

The non-related science fiction series Outlaw Star has a similar warp space that does have several instances of combat and collision, so maybe I am just remembering that. It also was a major plot point of Thor Ragnarok.

Comment: In TNG:S1:E1 - Encounter at Farpoint - the Enterprise goes to maximum warp, fires torpedos at the hostile entity giving chase, and detaches the saucer section while at warp. Seems like a battle - http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/101.htm

Comment: One possibility (without re-watching the episode) is the TNG episode where the Enterprise collides with a Quantum Filament (can't remember if the Enterprise is travelling at warp speed)

Comment: In ToS:S3:E13 Elaan of Troyius, the Enterprise was hampered because it couldn't enter warp for a battle, claiming that it was too sluggish.  This implies most battles occured at warp speeds.

Comment: @NKCampbell There is the question of whether the encounter at far point example was an illusion. I would say there’s some debate there, although the willingness of their participation supports it being a possible maneuver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USS Vengeance catches up to USS Enterprise and attacks it while the latter is at warp in Star Trek: Into Darkness. They're effectively engaged in combat therein. You can watch the scene in question [here](https://youtu.be/y8BYyBLsCUk).

Comment: This occurs in the Kelvin Timeline, wherein "warp" is really transwarp acquired by studying the *Narada*.

Comment: @The Daleks, could you please point me to a reputable source, preferably a video clip, where this has been canonically posited?

Answer (score 0):

In season 1 episode "Fallen Hero" of Star Trek: Enterprise the NX-01 Enterprise is pursued and attacked at warp speed by the aliens of the week the Mazarites and attempts to fight back with spatial torpedoes.

While proving helpful in showing that one can apparently fire projectiles at warp speed quite safely the torpedo does sod all in terms of damage as usual and the ship is forced to drop to impulse to be able to be able to use it's fancy new phase cannons without destabilising it's warp field and severely damaging or destroying the ship, this issue was rectified in time for the start of the second season by unknown means.