# Do any non-Federation starships have deflector dishes?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, technology

One of the answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232691/why-dont-some-federation-ships-have-deflector-dishes) says

> The visible dish itself is a bit **unique to the Federation**. (emphasis added)

Is that true? Do any non-Federation ships have deflector dishes?

Comment: Does this count; https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3zOj.png. Not a dish, more of a ring

Comment: There is no honour in deflector rings! A true Klingon deflects particles by [strapping the bodies of his enemies to his ship's hull](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Vulcan_Hello_(episode))!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Cardassian Galor class ships](https://intl.startrek.com/article/designing-the-first-cardassian-warship) have a navigational deflector - a blue or red square under the forward parts of the ship:

[image: Cardassian Galor class with blue deflector]

> Lighting was set up in several circuits: impulse engines, collectors, windows, navigational deflector, navigational beacons. Windows and **the navigational deflector were lit with custom neon tubes**; other lights were incandescent bulbs.
>
> <sub><sup>[Designing The First Cardassian Warship](https://intl.startrek.com/article/designing-the-first-cardassian-warship)</sup></sub>

[image: Cardassian Galor class with red deflector]

> The color of **the deflector array at the very front of the ship** was originally yellow or orange in TNG: "The Wounded" and "Ensign Ro". The color was later consistently switched to red, also on the CGI versions for later seasons of DS9. Strangely the publicity shots of the Galor on the box of the Ertl model kit or in Star Trek Mechanics show a blue deflector like it was never on screen.
>
> <sub><sup>[Ex Astris Scientia - Cardassian Ship Classes](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/cardassian_ships.htm)</sup></sub>

[image: Galor class starship schematic]

Comment: Much improved with the quotes.